# My select statement with PDO its not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here I store my login session in my $userId variable to get my id:

```
$ userId = $_SESSION['result']['id'];
```

Here I store a $_SESSION['where'] if the user wants to search for some name:

```
 if(isset($_POST['sendFiltro'])){
            $search = $_POST['search'];
            if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Name:'){
                $_SESSION['where'] = "AND name LIKE '%$search%'";
                header('Location: index2.php?exe=adminis/admins');
            }else{
                unset($_SESSION['where']);
                header('Location: index2.php?exe=adminis/adminis');
            }
        }
```

Here I do my select statment to get my admins to show in a table:

```
$pag = (empty($_GET['pag']) ? '1' : $_GET['pag']);
$max = 10;
$first = ($pag * $max) - $first;
$where = isset($_SESSION['where']) ? $_SESSION['where'] : '';
$readAdmin = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from admins WHERE id != :id {$where} ORDER BY name ASC, level ASC LIMIT :first, :max");
$readAdmin->bindParam(':id', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readAdmin->bindParam(':first', $first, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$readAdmin->bindParam(':max', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$readAdmin->execute();
$readAdminRows = $readAdmin->rowCount();
 if(!$readAdminRows)
    {
       echo 'There are no recors in admins table';
    }
    else
   {
    //I show my table
    }
```

I have 20 recors in my Admins table, and its always saying that I dont have recors in my admin table.

Do you see some error in my code for this to be happening?

If i remove this from my sql statment `WHERE id != :id` it works, but I dont want to show in the table the current admin with his session.

Comment: why is it {$where} instead of ".$where." ?

Comment: You should be using placeholders for **everything** and not just some of the things. `$where` is completely unescaped here. Are you seriously allowing arbitrary injection of SQL from the session?

Comment: @MrJack That's how [PHP string interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) works. Why do so many people not know this?

Comment: Thanks for your point tadman, but I dont know other method to do this!

Comment: @tadman Some of us learned to code other languages before PHP ;)

Comment: Well I've never seen a language that didnt take concatenation, so I only use that. Pointless to learn rare fads when something works just as well. Still wont use it but nice to know that we can use random brackets, that way, if I have to use some and it breaks, I'll know why :)

Comment: I'd rather ask why so many people, who have no idea on very basic language syntax, are so eager to comment or even answer

Comment: @CesarM, have you verified that $userId has a value? Is it really numeric?

Comment: @YourCommonSense LOLPHP <-- its not a real language, that's why.

Comment: @MrJack I'd rather blame not a wand but a wizard, you know

Comment: @Robbert it doesn't matter

Comment: Yes Robbert my  echo $userId; returns the id of the admin logged.

Comment: Time to look at error generated by your query.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Tadman, sorry my question but Im not very savvy on php yet, and I do not see the real problem, in this case, of using my $where without using bindparam method?

Answer (score 0):

```
$readAdminRows = $readAdmin->rowCount();
```

The rowCount() function always returns 0 if you configure PDO to use unbuffered queries:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

I'd suggest instead that you try to fetch the first row of the result set, and if the first fetch still returns nothing, then you have no matches.